# Graticule label orientation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-10.3, grids-graticules

I have a lat/long graticule set in my data frame. All looks good, except that the labels on the right and left read horizontally, when I'd like them vertically. I see them on other maps, so I know it can be done, but can't find how to accomplish this in any searches. Ideas?

Comment: I am using version 10.5.1 and the labels cannot be turned this way whatever I try. Amazing how such a simple thing cannot be achieved in ArcGIS...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Reference System Properties dialog go to Labels tab -> Label Oriantation (bottom of dialog)
[image]

Comment: I thought I'd tried that, but will try again when I get home.

Comment: You need to click Apply in ESRI products, clicking OK is not enough as it cancels the changes.

Comment: Clicking OK does not cancel the changes. You just have to remember to click OK on both the Reference System Properties dialog and the Data Frame Properties dialog. This just tested in ArcGIS 10.3.1